# Why does not client connect to tcp server by 3G?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

we have server with the TCP socket. There is no problem if client(mobile phone) connects with the Wi-Fi connection. But if client tries to connect to the socket with the 3G connection, it doesn’t connect anywise.

The code in the client side:

```
    mikrofon = new Socket(); 
    SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(serverip, port);
    mikrofon.connect(address);
```

Note: If client pings the server with telnet via 3G connection, it gets response. But inside our application we could not connect, it throws timeout exception. we set timeout unlimited, still does not connect.

Comment: You can try sniff traffic on server to understand is it network problem or problem with server.

Comment: Is 'serverip' a public IP address?

Comment: @Steve yes serverip is public.

Comment: we have tried with different operator 3G network, it works. Is it possible that the cause of problem is operator?

Comment: Are you able to connect (via Telnet) on exactly the same server *IP* and *port* you are using in the application? When you say from a client mobile phone, how is your set up exactly? (Is it some Android app, or is it a PC that uses a mobile phone as its data provider?)

Comment: yes i connected on same server ip. it is android application and the server written with java.